# Tier Pricing For Configurable Products

Tags: configurable-product, tiered-pricing

Is there any way to implement tier pricing for different variations of a configurable product. For example, the site would have the option of buying 12 products and receive a 10% discount.
The user would be able to add from all type of variations (small, medium, large) to get to 12 and receive the discount.

Thanks

Comment: you can create discount rule on a particular category

Comment: Thanks. But this applies to the entire site as well as we need it to be 10% off the price of "each" product. Not 10% off the entire order. So if from the same category they chose a total of 12 from 2 different products they wouldn't be eligible for the discount

Comment: Both the things are one on the same applying discount on individual products or on whole cart it will give you the same discount if you haven't applied any other discount to it

Comment: which magento version you are using?

Comment: I'm on version 2.1.9

Comment: Can you explain how to set it up? Because I've been playing around the backend with no success...

Comment: check my answer & reply if facing any problem

Comment: Thanks. But that will only work if the customer enters a discount code upon check out. I want the discount to be applied upon adding orders to cart...a cart rule. Also, just another piece of information to keep in mind. The site has over 30k Products... So we need to figure out a way to have thousands of rules as well...let me know if you think of anything...

Comment: Also - this will apply to each product individually so customers can't combine 2 Products to reach 12...

Comment: you can put this rule without discount coupon aswell

Comment: Would so many cart rules affect the site speed?

Comment: there is no need to create so many cart rules you can achieve these with a single rule only but the thing is you need to create multiple conditions into the single rule

Comment: the concern of yours is when user puts 10  products into cart he/she should get a discount of 10%, So what matter if he/she enters 10 quantities of a single product into cart the ultimate goal of yours is to make the user buy 10 products from your site

Comment: If you actually want it in a different way then you need to create it programmatically

Comment: I only want to have the discount apply when they purchse 10 items of a particular configurable product. So if they buy 10 items from diff oarent products it wont apply...

Answer (score 0):

To set the discount rates just go to your backend Admin panel & traverse to the below location

> **Admin > marketing > Cart Price Rule > Add New Rule**

than fill the form as described in the Images below

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then click the save button & look at your frontend

If facing any problem let me know

Thank You!

> Note: Here I have used 25% you can use of your wish & I have used
>   coupon to avail the discount If you don't want any coupon you can skip
>   it.

Comment: If my answer helped you do vote & accept it so it can help others also facing same problem or want help!

Answer (score -1):

This is exactly what our extension [tier price for configurable products (M2)](https://marketplace.magento.com/customgento-module-configurable-tier-prices-m2.html) does. It updates the tier price calculation as you described and has the following additional features:

- tier price calculation across multiple variations
- updated calculation can be disabled for each configurable product
- updated calculation can be disabled for each category
- [new] tier price calculation type can be configured:

  - use the highest tier price
  - use the lowest tier price
  - use the tier price of the respective product

You can find some screenshots on our [docs page](http://docs.customgento.com/tier-prices-for-configurable-products-m2.html).

Mind that the extension only works for Magento >= 2.2 since some serious configurable product bugs have been fixed in this version. But if you still use Magento 2.1, you should upgrade anyway :-)